# How to update unique values in SQL using a PostgreSQL sequence?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequences

In SQL, how do update a table, setting a column to a different value for each row?

I want to update some rows in a PostgreSQL database, setting one column to a number from a sequence, where that column has a unique constraint. I hoped that I could just use:

```
update person set unique_number = (select nextval('number_sequence') );
```

but it seems that *nextval* is only called once, so the update uses the same number for every row, and I get a 'duplicate key violates unique constraint' error. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Don't use a subselect, rather use the nextval function directly, like this:

```
update person set unique_number = nextval('number_sequence');
```

Comment: Thanks - that works. I got caught by the sub-select because I was trying to use the same sequence number for two columns, but I don't really need to do that.

Comment: If you want to re-use the same sequence value after you have called nextval('sequence') , you can use the related function currval('sequence'), which returns the current sequence.

Answer (score -1):

I consider pg's sequences a hack and signs that incremental integers aren't the best way to key rows.  Although pgsql didn't get native support for UUIDs until 8.3

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/datatype-uuid.html

The benefits of UUID is that the combination are nearly infinite, unlike a random number which will hit a collision one day.

Comment: "Nearly infinite?"  The docs say it's a 128-bit integer type.  That's a lot, but it isn't infinite, and it is nearly certain to collide before all 2^128 values are used.  Additionally, ORMs will likely have to convert to/from string types to use this.  Not a clear win in my view.

Comment: I think you under estimate how big 2^128 is, go read up about uuid on Wikipedia.

Comment: It's mostly academic, but a Postgres sequence can be more collision-proof than a UUID depending on how it is created.  Python's `uuid` module uses a random component, but substantially less than 128 random bits.  Sequences only collide if they cycle, random numbers collide ... randomly.

Comment: Postgres has its own uuid generator - which I haven't seen - but it may well be better than Python's, fwiw.